# How to change the Institute name from the template

Tags: templates

I am new to Latex. I have to write thesis for my MS. For that I search latex templates and find one template at http://web.mit.edu/thesis/tex/
I edit the template accordingly but not able to change the institute name. Can anyone help me changing the name. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open the template and overwrite the name in template. It should be easily find with editor (find function).

Comment: Read the Copyrights first. But you can use on preamble `\def\MIT{MASSACHUSETTS INSTITUTE OF TECHNOLOGY}
\def\Mit{Massachusetts Institute of Technology}`

Comment: @Sigur: As long as the OP does not change the `mitthesis.cls` explicitly the redefinition of `\MIT` or `\Mit` should be no issue at all. The question is rather, if this class can be applied to a document that should not be a MIT thesis at all (otherwise the name change would be not really useful)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, this is the reason I suggested the OP to read the Copyrights before to use and change the template.

Comment: @Sigur: Oh, I thought you just mean the redefinition of the macros itself ;-)

Comment: When I give my suggestion I hope that the OP is aware of copyright issues of template.

Comment: @Zarko: Well, you implied that ;-) Again, this is the usual template crisis ... formatting issues, copyright issues ... that's why I don't like templates

Comment: @Sigur Feel free to answer the question. Please don't forget the copyright issue.

Answer (score 2):

The MIT Thesis Template is meant for writing a thesis at MIT. It is not suited for other universities.

You can redefine the name of the institution using

```
\renewcommand{\MIT}{SCHOOL OF DUCK SCIENCE}
\renewcommand{\mit}{School of Duck Science}.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an update related to this old post.  A new MIT thesis template was released in 2023, and it is available in CTAN: https://ctan.org/pkg/mitthesis

This new latex template allows changing the institutional information shown on the cover page, including the name of school, copyright details, and "chairman" or acceptor information (see the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/mitthesis/mitthesis-doc/mitthesis-doc.pdf)
).